# reload visualforce page after displaying custom message

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I've got a Visualforce Page that is just a form with a Save button.

I'm trying to display a message if the record is inserted correctly or not, and if it is inserted correctly I want to reload the page and delete every value stored in the form.

I have this Apex Code:

```
public PageReference save() {
        try {
            upsert accRecord;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Record submited successfully'));
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            //ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Account Name'));
            return null;
        }
        //  After successful Save, navigate to the default view page        
        PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage(); 
        tempPage.setRedirect(true);
        return tempPage;
        //return null;
    }
```

Right now it doesn't show the message, but if I delete the PageReference tempPage variable and leave `return null` it will show the message and but stay in the same page with the values of the inserted record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `upsert` your record, reset it to an empty value, then rerender the page. All the field values stored on the page will pull empty values from the new record instead.

```
    try {
        upsert accRecord;
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Record submited successfully'));

        accRecord = new Account(); 
        return null; 
    } catch(System.DMLException e) {
        //ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Account Name'));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If this answer helped, consider up voting it, or accepting it as the best answer. You can read more about how rep works here:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote